# Django validation exception from Model Manager create method

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models

I am using a custom Django model Manager to create an instance. The fields of the instance are derived from data fetched from a given URL. One of the fields is a filename containing a JSON report that I need to open. My question is - if I determine an error has occurred (file not found, content not valid, etc.), is it reasonable to throw an exception in a create() method and is there a preferred exception type to throw?

The model needs the parsed data to create a valid instance so I would already know the model is not valid before executing the create() method.

```
class IndexingUpdateRunManager(models.Manager):
    def create_from_run(self,run_history_url):
        run_info_dict = self.extract_fields_from_url(run_history_url)
        run_config_file = run_info_dict["run_config_file"]
        report_filename = run_info_dict["status_report_file"]
        try:
            out_fh = open(report_filename,'r')
            report_data = json.loads(out_fh)
            status_code=report_data["status"]
        except Exception, e:
            # throw an exception?
    this_run=self.create(run_config_file_used=run_config_file,
                         report_filename = report_filename,
                         run_status_code=status_code)
    return this_run

class MyUpdateRun(models.Model):
    run_config_file_used = models.FilePathField(max_length=1024,
                               help_text="config file for run")
    report_filename = models.FilePathField(max_length=1024,
                               help_text="status report file for run")
    run_status_code = models.IntegerField(help_text="status code for overall run execution")
    objects = MyUpdateRunManager()

>>MyUpdateRun.objects.create_from_run("https://server/job_status/builds/200/")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can raise one ObjectDoesNotExist ( from django.core.exceptions ) and as well you can create your own exception call like:

class MyException(ObjectDoesNotExist):
   pass

and raise it in some specific situation that Django doesn't provide a satisfying exception.

Ps.: Your exception can still inherit from the base exception:
class MyException(Exception):
   pass